# Java static method parameters

Tags: java, static, parameters, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Why does the following code return `100 100 1 1 1` and not `100 1 1 1 1` ?

```
public class Hotel {
private int roomNr;

public Hotel(int roomNr) {
    this.roomNr = roomNr;
}

public int getRoomNr() {
    return this.roomNr;
}

static Hotel doStuff(Hotel hotel) {
    hotel = new Hotel(1);
    return hotel;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Hotel h1 = new Hotel(100);
    System.out.print(h1.getRoomNr() + " ");
    Hotel h2 = doStuff(h1);
    System.out.print(h1.getRoomNr() + " ");
    System.out.print(h2.getRoomNr() + " ");
    h1 = doStuff(h2);
    System.out.print(h1.getRoomNr() + " ");
    System.out.print(h2.getRoomNr() + " ");
}
}
```

Why does it appear to pass Hotel by-value to doStuff() ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: Java passes by value. See linked question. (Also, `static` has nothing to do with it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does exactly what you told it to do :-)

```
Hotel h1 = new Hotel(100);
System.out.print(h1.getRoomNr() + " "); // 100
Hotel h2 = doStuff(h1);
System.out.print(h1.getRoomNr() + " "); // 100 - h1 is not changed, h2 is a distinct new object
System.out.print(h2.getRoomNr() + " "); // 1
h1 = doStuff(h2);
System.out.print(h1.getRoomNr() + " "); // 1 - h1 is now changed, h2 not
System.out.print(h2.getRoomNr() + " "); // 1
```

As others noted (and is explained very clearly [in this article](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)), Java passes by value. In this case, it passes a copy of the reference `h1` to `doStuff`. There the copy gets overwritten with a new reference (which is then returned and assigned to `h2`), but the original value of `h1` is not affected: it still references the first Hotel object with a room number of 100.

Answer (score 5):

Reference to Hotel is passed by value.

Answer (score 4):

Because Java *does* pass by value.  Only in this case, the value is a reference to a `Hotel` object.  Or to be more clear, Java passes a reference to the same Object that h1 points to.  Therefore, h1 itself is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

The Hotel reference is passed by value. You're only changing the local `hotel` variable in the `doStuff` method and returning it, not changing the original `h1`. You *could* change the original `h1` from within the method if you had a setRoomNr method and called `hotel.setRoomNr(1)` though...

Answer (score 1):

It is doing fine. Inside `static Hotel doStuff(Hotel hotel)`, you are creating a `new` instance of of `Hotel`, old `hotel` reference is unchanged.